# Connect existing SQL Server database to default MVC individual user account database

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a database that I've created. I also have created a new ASP.NET MVC application using Individual User Account boilerplate code to get started. I notice that my `web.config` is pointing to a default location. I want to keep the boilerplate code and bring in my data model using Entity Framework so that.  However user authentication tables and the tables I have created are in 2 different databases.  What is the best way to resolve this?

Ultimately I just want to use the ASP.NET MVC authentication and bring in my data using Entity Framework and have both my data and the user account tables in the same database. If there is a better approach to doing this all together I am all ears.

Comment: Your web.config should have two connectionstrings, one for each DB.

Comment: You can create connection string for different databases with different names in web.config, then bind newly created connection string with EF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an attribute on each Individual User that has their own connection string so that every time you create a new db context, you do it passing their connection string attribute, then the context would be pointing to the correct database each time.